# I want to diplay the contents of a file in a text box after being selected in a listbox 

Tags: c#, silverlight

I push a button and a list all the files in my given path appears in a listbox.

```
        IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Desktop\Stuffs\Dummi", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var f in files)
        {

            lbz.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}", f));
```

I want to be able to select a file from the list and open it's contents in a text box below the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SteveDog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265825/105570) should work fine for small files.

If you have large files, this may lock up the UI as the file's contents are read. In that case you could use a `BackgroundWorker` to read the file:

```
ListBox lbz;
TextBox tbx;
BackgroundWorker bgw;

void lbz_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgw.IsBusy)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(lbz.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = File.ReadAllText((string)e.Argument);
}

void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    tbx.Text = (string)e.Result;
}
```

Comment: Hey Dan thanks alot =) I get NullReferenceException when selecting on item in the list

Comment: @FamenZ: Have you tried using the debugger to identify what is `null`? Obviously you need to initialize the `BackgroundWorker` (you can actually drag and drop one from the "Components" section of the Forms Designer toolbox right onto the form in Visual Studio). Beyond that, I'm not sure what to tell you; the debugger is your friend when it comes to figuring out what might be `null`.

Comment: bgw is null >.< Should have said that, and your right, I need to initialize the BackgroundWorker, I'm working with visual Web Developer..

Comment: @FamenZ: Ah, sorry, missed that you're developing for Silverlight. I *believe* you should still be fine; you can initialize a `BackgroundWorker` just like you would any other component through code (`bgw = new BackgroundWorker()`). You'll just need to wire up the event handlers yourself.

Comment: I'm new to this if you can't tell >.<

Comment: @FamenZ: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint inside the `bgw_DoWork` method to make sure it's called. If it isn't, you haven't wired up the event handler (you need to do `bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork)`. Otherwise put a breakpoint inside `bgw_RunWorkerCompleted`. Maybe the result is blank for some reason. In any case, just use the debugger! Trust me, it'll clarify things a lot more quickly than I or anyone else on SO can ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will load the contents of the file that is named in the selected item into a text box:

```
TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(lbz.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

This is the simplest and easiest method.  It will work well for smaller files, but if the files you need to load are larger, it could take a long time to load the file and it will lock up the UI while it loads it.  If that is an issue, you would need to do the work of loading the file on a separate thread.

Comment: -1 because it is a poor solution. What happen if the file is few MB or GB?

Comment: @Thunder Granted, but I assumed based on the scenario that the files would be relatively small.  How often do you want to load a few GB of text into a text box?